# theres something like clearsOnBeginEditing for use in SwiftUI project?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I need to clear up TextField from default amount when i click to TextField

I have find solution for Storyboard project but not for SwiftUI

Answer (score 1):

You could use `@FocusState` for this and clear the field in a `onChange(of:)` modifier.

Here is a simple example that clears a text field every time it gets focus

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var field1 = ""
    @State var field2 = ""
    @FocusState private var field1InFocus: Bool

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Field 1", text: $field1)
                .focused($field1InFocus)
            TextField("Field 2", text: $field2)
        }
        .onChange(of: field1InFocus) { inFocus in
            if inFocus {
                field1 = ""
            }
        }
    }
}
```